# MVC3 + Ninject - How to?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, ninject

I've just started playing with IoC containers and therefore chosed Ninject.

After several hours of sweat and tears I still cant figure out how to setup my MVC3 application with Ninject.

So far I have:

Global.asax.cs

```
public class MvcApplication : Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectHttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }

    protected void Application_Start() 
    {
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new MyDependencyResolver(CreateKernel()));
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var modules = new [] { new ServiceModule() };
        return new StandardKernel(modules);
    }

}

ServiceModule.cs

internal class ServiceModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IGreetingService>().To<GreetingService>();
    }
}
```

MyDependencyResolver.cs

```
public class MyDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private IKernel kernel;

    public MyDependencyResolver(IKernel kernel)
    { 
        this.kernel = kernel; 
    }

    public object GetService(System.Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.TryGet(serviceType);

    }

    public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object> GetServices(System.Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.GetAll(serviceType);

    }
}
```

GreetingService.cs

```
public interface IGreetingService
{
    string Hello();
}

public class GreetingService : IGreetingService
{
    public string Hello()
    {
        return "Hello from GreetingService";
    }
}
```

TestController.cs

```
public class TestController : Controller
{

    private readonly IGreetingService service;

    public TestController(IGreetingService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index", service.Hello());
    }

}
```

Each time I try to load the Index view it either just throws a overflow exception or a HTTP 404 error - If I remove all the Ninject code it works perfectly, whats wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are mixing an own dependency resolver with the MVC extension. I'd suggest either going with your own dependency resolver or with using the MVC extension but not both. **When using the MVC extension you have to use OnApplicationStarted instead of Application_Start.**

See http://www.planetgeek.ch/2010/11/13/official-ninject-mvc-extension-gets-support-for-mvc3/ and have a look at the SampleApplication that comes with the source code of the MVC extension https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc.

Also the fix is not used anymore when you use the current version for the build server: http://teamcity.codebetter.com

---

UPDATE: The `Ninject.MVC3` package continues to be updated and works OOTB against MVC4 RTM (and RC). See [this page in the wiki](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/MVC3) for details.

Comment: -1.  I went to your link to download your sample app.  It's missing files and won't compile

Comment: @Christian Payne All is there. Just read the how too! The CI Server ensures it is buildable

Comment: you have to use OnApplicationStarted and inherite from `NinjectHttpApplication`? where do I put my legacy `void Global_PostReleaseRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)`,`public override void Init()`, and `void Global_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)` ?

Comment: The API has changed too much over time, though I can tell a lot of this might have been brought about by changes to the MVC framework.  This is a fairly simple concept and yet I've been reading conflicting documentation and blogs for quite some time now.