# Ninject + Bind generic repository

Tags: c#, ioc-container, ninject

I'm trying to Bind a generic IRepository<> interface to my generic Repository<> - however it always return null?

I have tried various things like:

```
Bind(typeof(IRepository<CustomerModel>)).To(typeof(Repository<CustomerModel>)); 
Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>));
```

However if I pass in a non-generic interface and class then it works like a dream?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

> ```
> Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>));
> ```

This is the correct syntax for binding an open generic.

If you are receiving null back when requesting `IRepository< of whatever >`, then there may be some other problem in an area of code you haven't shared.

Comment: Perfect! - Yes you were right. My Repository consturctor depended on a Interface - I now also have binded the Interface used by my Repository and it works! - Thanks.

Comment: @qes What would be the syntax if IRepository takes more than one type argument (i.e. `IRepository<T,U>`). Please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/6740992/88709 Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

See my answer on [MVC3 Controller constructor + Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369086/mvc3-controller-constructor-ninject/4370568#4370568).

Generic Binding works correctly in Ninject. Try using a parameterless constructor in Repository. I think the problem is there.