# Ninject: How to bind an open generic with more than one type argument?

Tags: c#, ninject-2

I'm using Ninject 2.2, and I'm trying to setup a binding for an open generic that takes two type arguments. According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370515/ninject-bind-generic-repository/4370596#4370596) by qes, the correct syntax to bind `IRepository<T>` to `Repository<T>` is this:

```
Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>));
```

The above syntax works perfectly if `IRepository` takes just one type argument, but breaks if it takes more (gives a `Using the generic type 'Repository<T,U>' requires 2 type arguments` compile time error.)

How can I bind `IRepository<T,U>` to `Repository<T,U>`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
Bind(typeof(IRepository<,>)).To(typeof(Repository<,>));
```

Try that....

Comment: Awesome! I would have never figured that out myself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: My hero!  It's so simple once you work out what to ask Google!

Comment: You rule! Never seen that kind of syntax before. Was just about to spoil my code with unnecessary generic types when I fortunately hit this post

Comment: You can also go from single type to double type, i.e. `Bind(typeof(IRepo<>)).To(typeof(Repo<,>));` etc.

Comment: Actually, when I try to bind from single type param to double type params, i get some "The number of generic arguments provided doesn't equal the arity of the generic type definition." exception