# Issue with binding the interface to class Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

I have an interface:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
    where T : Entity
{
    T Add(T entity);
    T Delete(int id);
    T Get(int id);
    T Update(T entity);
    IQueryable<T> Items { get; }
}
```

and class:

```
public class EfRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : Entity
```

However, I am having problems in binding them, so here is Binding code and it keeps highlighting the

```
private void AddBindings()
    {
        ninjectKernel.Bind<IRepository<T>>().To<EfRepository<T>>();
    }
```

Comment: Sounds obvious, T is not recognized in your scope where you create the bindings.

Comment: @Complexity, could you please help with the code, what shall I do so that my code works? I would very grateful.

Comment: I've added an answer, however it's untested, please give it a try.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370515/ninject-bind-generic-repository

Answer (score 1):

This is because in the class where you create the bindings, it's not aware of T.

What you're looking for is binding open generics.
That can be achieved using something like this:

> ```
> Bind(typeof(IGeneric<>)).To(typeof(Generic<>));
> ```

Give it a try, I guess it should work (however, it's untested).

In your case, it means your code will look like:

```
private void AddBindings()
{
    ninjectKernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(EfRepository<>));
}
```

Comment: i've tried to edit the answer (but some of the reviewers seemingly are not that familiar with c# and rejected the edit). So could you please adjust the example yourself? (change `Bind<IRepository<>>()` to `Bind(typeof(IRepository<>))`. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, cool. I've taken the liberty to fix the parantheses since they were not quite perfect yet ;-)

Comment: No problem. I wrote this without a computer so I couldn't test it.