# How do I fix "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject, asp.net-mvc-4

I created an mvc4 project in visual studio 2012 RC, and added the ninject.mvc3 package using nuget.  It created the standard NinjectWebCommon.cs file and I edited the RegisterServices method like so:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<IProfileRepository>().To<ProfileRepository>().InSingletonScope(); 
        }
```

Here is my interface and profile repository class:

```
public interface IProfileRepository
    {
        void CreateProfile(UserProfile profile);
    }



public class ProfileRepository : IProfileRepository
    {
        private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

        public void CreateProfile(UserProfile userProfile)
        {
            context.UserProfiles.Add(userProfile);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
```

I want to access this my IProfileRepository in my Account Controller like so:

```
        private readonly IProfileRepository profileRepository;

        public AccountController(IProfileRepository repo){
            profileRepository = repo;
        }
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Attempt to register the user
                MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
                Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, passwordQuestion: null, passwordAnswer: null, isApproved: true, providerUserKey: null, status: out createStatus);

                if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
                {
                    profileRepository.CreateProfile(new UserProfile
                    {
                        UserId = (Guid)Membership.GetUser(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey,
                        FirstName = model.FirstName,
                        LastName = model.LastName,
                        School = model.School,
                        Major = model.Major
                    });
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, createPersistentCookie: false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

I get an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error when my `profileRepostory` object is called, hence its probably not being injected.  Does anyone know whats wrong?  Thanks!

EDIT:
Here is my global.asax file:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just for ensure: are your Ninject dependency resolver registered in MVC?

Comment: Could you please check content of NinjectWebCommon.cs file? Is there something like DependencyResolver.SetResolver(...)?

Comment: @STO No there is not, how would i go about adding it?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358395/mvc3-ninject-how-to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you changed the configuration, Ninject will throw an `ActivationException` rather than inject `null` for a dependency. You should check which object is really `null`.

E.g. Allowing anonymous access is a huge hint that `HttpContext.User` is what is null.