# ASP.NET MVC Error loading Ninject component ICache

Tags: ninject.web.mvc

I've been getting the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Error loading Ninject component ICache
No such component has been registered in the kernel's component container.
```

Using the following NuGet packages:

- Ninject 3.0.1.10
- Ninject.MVC3 3.0.0.6
- Ninject.Web.Common 3.0.0.7
- ASP.NET MVC 4.0.30506.0

The Binding are setup using WebActivator and the Ninject Bootstrapper (default setup).

It appears this error was once an issue before [Ninject 2.2.1.0 and Ninject.MVC3 2.2.1.0 were released](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/03/01/ninject-2-2-1-0-and-ninject-mvc3-2-2-1-0-released/) and this article is similar but I'm not using Web.Api 
[Error loading Ninject component ICache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757142/error-loading-ninject-component-icache).

It might be worth noting that I have two Kernels. The main kernel is created at application start-up and is disposed on shutdown. The second kernel us used during start-up but is disposed almost immediately as it's not needed again. So would this possibly cause the issue?

Comment: Are you using WebApi? Might be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757142/error-loading-ninject-component-icache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue was due to the fact that there were two Kernels. They must have been conflicting somehow, I didn't determine the cause and opted to remove the second Kernel.

Comment: how would you go about figuring out how 2 kernels might be getting created?

Comment: In my case I just search for usages of `StandardKernel`

Answer (score 4):

In my case this was because I was following [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212561/using-ninject-di-for-both-api-and-regular-controllers-in-mvc4)'s `System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver` Ninject wrapper where the `Dispose()` method would call dispose on the kernel.