# What is the correct way to Dispose of managed resources in IDependencyScope

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject, idisposable

I have the following implementation of `IDependencyScope`:

```
public class NinjectScope : IDependencyScope
{
    protected IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot;

    public NinjectScope(IResolutionRoot kernel)
    {
        resolutionRoot = kernel;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        IRequest request = resolutionRoot.CreateRequest(serviceType, null, new Parameter[0], true, true);
        return resolutionRoot.Resolve(request).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        IRequest request = resolutionRoot.CreateRequest(serviceType, null, new Parameter[0], true, true);
        return resolutionRoot.Resolve(request).ToList();
    }

    ~NinjectScope()
    {
        this.Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        IDisposable disposable = (IDisposable)this.resolutionRoot;

        if (disposing)
        {
            // Free managed resources
            if (this.resolutionRoot != null)
            {
                disposable.Dispose();
                this.resolutionRoot = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see it has `Dispose(bool disposing)` implemented.

I was experiencing the error `Error loading Ninject component ICache` when I added a Ninject Factory into one of my WebAPI classes.

[As per this answer/question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23204137/894792) I realised that I was using the same implementation, except it wasn't my kernel being disposed of, it was being caused by the implementation of the `Dispose(bool disposing)` method.

When I removed the implementation, the dependencies in my WebAPI Controller stopped causing the error, so it seems that the implementation of the `Dispose(bool disposing)` method was causing the problem.

**What is the correct implementation of `Dispose()` for this particular class?**

By calling the following to create the item that I am calling dispose on:

```
IRequest request = resolutionRoot.CreateRequest(serviceType, null, new Parameter[0], true, true);
```

[I learned from this answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10242470/894792) that only the object that created a disposable resource should call dispose, so maybe there aren't any things within my class that need disposing of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `resolutionRoot` is passed in via the constructor, it may be shared by other objects, and therefore it's unsafe to dispose of it from inside of `NinjectScope`.

Whatever code created that `resolutionRoot` object should also dispose of it again when it's no longer needed.

In my experience, though, a single DI Container instance tends to be around for the lifetime of the application, so it may only be meaningful to dispose of it once the application exits.

Comment: Sorry, you're quite right... it is that object that is being disposed of and being passed in.  Naturally it is indeed wrong to dispose of that in there. Thank you